# How to give space between recycle view specific items at run time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recycle view items being shown in form of card views ,it is working correctly.

Scenario is i have categories in items and each category items are in ascending order , what i want is spacing between category items ,these category items depend what user has added.

So after each category list items a spacing will occur at run time and then rest of list items as usual will show and if another category appears again spacing should provide the space. Below is the image.

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: getting all recycleview list items now i am trying to add view space at run time by checking condtion or using  counter to check number of items in each category on behave of that space will be added.

Comment: Can you put your xml code here and the array response your are getting to display a list. I have a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare items, after each category add temp category(for space) inside your list. Then inflate in adapter using Heterogenous layouts inside RecyclerView i.e you can use multiple viewholders as list items. In your case one type will be of CardView and other will be blank layout(for space) and return item like this:-

```
  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if (items.get(position) instanceof cardCategory) {
        return CardLayout;
      } else if (items.get(position) instanceof spaceCategory) {
        return SpaceLayout;
      }
    return -1;
  }
```

For more info, search Heterogeneous layouts inside RecyclerView. Hope this will resolve your problem.